# why cypher queries or may be neo4j gives low perfomance?

Tags: java, performance, neo4j, cypher

I am using neo4j 2.0-M5 community version of Neo4j.

I have created nodes using the JDBC driver from [here](https://github.com/dmontag/neo4j-import), unfortunately I  didn't  take care of auto indexing, but  created **labels**. I have 50 million nodes, 160 million properties and 10 relationships. I execute this query using Java Neo4j embedded API

```
MATCH(names:DAR)
with names limit 200000
where names.name <> null
and (names.name =~ ".* (?i)SHAIK$" or names.name =~ "(?i)SHAIK .*$"
or names.name =~ ".* (?i)SHAIK .*$" or names.name =~ "(?i)SHAIK" )
AND NOT(names.name =~ '.(?i)shekar.$')
AND NOT(names.name =~ '.(?i)shekhar.$')
AND NOT(names.name =~ '.(?i)sheker.$')
return names as names1
```

It takes **40 sec in cypher console**, **2 minutes** in Java Neo4j embedded API.
OK, fine, later i process these using the following code

```
Iterator<Node> resultNode1 = result.columnAs("names1");  
while (resultNode1.hasNext()) {
     System.out.println("after ddd"+Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
}
```

For the first record it takes a few seconds, but for the last record it **takes 5 minutes**.

I tried with different inputs like, SHAeK and sheek. If 100 records are in the iterator it takes seconds for the first 99 records and 5 minutes for the 100th record.

I am unable to increase the perfomance, please help me?

Comment: Just to be clear: 5 crore = 50 million? So you have 50 million nodes, and you're executing up to 7 regular expression checks against 200,000 nodes at a time? Just a guess, since I haven't tried this, but I'm thinking this takes an enormous amount of CPU...

Comment: is there any alternative for this?

Comment: but we are applying on 200000 nodes only ,

Comment: If not legacy indexing, do you use a label index? What happens if you run `CREATE INDEX ON :DAR(name)`, give the index time to populate, and then run your query, any difference?

Comment: sorry to mention,   executed  CREATE INDEX ON :DAR(name) before running app

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see here is that your Cypher query that is being generated from your driver is heavily reliant on RegEx instead of Lucene.

The cost of running a complex regular expression like the one you have provided, over the 200,000 records that you are matching, is computationally expensive. I suggest that you first limit the amount of records you would like to match and then perform your regular expression match. A manageable amount of records would be sub 100 for a reasonable execution time.

If this is infeasible for your application then I would consider an indexing strategy that allows you to make use of Lucene query to perform your matching instead of using labels + RegEx.

Cheers,

Kenny

Comment: thanks for your replay ,but jdbc importer  don't have auto indexing support